# uitable view button action

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

in my table view  i have a button in each cell

```
UIButton *editButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
editButton.frame = CGRectMake(281,0, 20, 50);
UIImage *editButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];
[editButton setImage:editButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[editButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[editButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:editButton];
```

and button acction is this

```
-(IBAction)editButtonAction:(id)sender{
     UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) btn.superview.superview;
     NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.table indexPathForCell:cell]; 
     int row = indexPath.row;
     NSLog(@"Selected row is: %d",row);
}
```

when i click button in table view **selected row is** always give 0
have any idea? and any code

Comment: have you tried @janusfidel answer....?

Comment: hi man it is working i tested the janusfidel's answer... i think your doing mistake in some other part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative solution:

```
.
.
editButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[editButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
.
.

-(IBAction)editButtonAction:(id)sender{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
NSLog(@"Selected row is: %d",btn.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you create button assign

set button tag as a index of tableView cell.

```
[editButton setTag:indexPath.row];
```

in button

```
-(IBAction)editButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0]];

    NSLog(@"Selected Cell is: %@",cell);
    NSLog(@"Selected row is: %d",[sender tag]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this method..

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

add this line:

```
  button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And in this button action ,

```
 -(IBAction)editButtonAction:(id)sender
```

add this line:

```
int row = [sender tag];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code works fine..Which row you selected for testing?is it 0?
Try logging both rows and section.

Also check the outlet of table connected?and if the reference changed anywhere for that outlet

Otherwise the code runs fine for me

```
    NSLog(@"Row: %d\n ,Section :%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section);;
```

Comment: @user1551089: wht is the section count?